# Docker: Angular container works, but machine node_modules are empty and a new volume is created each time

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, node-modules

I have an Angular container for development and hot-reload enabled. one of the problems I've found is that, on Visual Studio code, all my files have a lot of errors, since the `node_modules` folder is empty. However, the application works and run fine.
The errors go If do `npm install` directly on my folder. Ideally I'd like to install the components and have them available on my machine and also the container.

In addition, each time I run my container with `docker compose -f development.yml up -d` a new volume is created, so I end up with a lot of volumes when I constantly turn on and off the service.

My Dockerfile is this:

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4200
```

Then I build the Dockerfile to have an image called `angular_frontend`.

And my Docker compose file is:

```
    services:
      angular-frontend:
        image: angular_frontend
        command: "npm run start-docker-dev"
        ports:
          - 4200:4200
        volumes:
          - /app/node_modules
          - .:/app
        hostname: frontend-localhost.domain.com
```

Also the `package.json` I'm using is:

```
    {
      "name": "frontend",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start-dev": "PROJECT=frontend ng serve --ssl --host frontend.domain.com",
        "start-docker-dev": "PROJECT=frontend ng serve --ssl --proxy-config docker.dev.proxy.conf.json --host frontend.domain.com --public-host frontend.domain.com",
        "build-prod": "PROJECT=frontend NODE_ENV=production ng build --configuration=production",
        "build-qa": "PROJECT=frontend NODE_ENV=production ng build --configuration=qa",
        "build-dev": "PROJECT=frontend ng build",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "test": "jest --coverage --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit --detectOpenHandles",
        "test-watch": "jest --watch",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~12.2.13",
        "@angular/common": "~12.2.13",
        "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.13",
        "@angular/core": "~12.2.13",
        "@angular/forms": "~12.2.13",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.13",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.13",
        "@angular/router": "~12.2.13",
        "@ed/subtract": "^2.4.1",
        "@fnando/sparkline": "^0.3.10",
        "chart.js": "^3.4.1",
        "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.0.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "ngx-cookie-service": "^12.0.0",
        "rxjs": "~6.6.6",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.0.4",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.13",
        "@angular-eslint/builder": "12.6.1",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "12.6.1",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "12.6.1",
        "@angular-eslint/schematics": "12.6.1",
        "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.6.1",
        "@angular/cli": "~12.2.13",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.13",
        "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.32",
        "@types/fnando__sparkline": "^0.3.3",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.168",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.28.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.28.2",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
        "eslint": "^7.26.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.3.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
        "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
        "jest": "^26.6.3",
        "jest-junit": "^12.0.0",
        "jest-preset-angular": "^8.3.2",
        "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
        "typescript": "~4.3.5"
      },
      "jest": {
        "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
        "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
          "<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts"
        ],
        "roots": [
          "<rootDir>/projects/a",
          "<rootDir>/projects/b"
        ],
        "modulePaths": [
          "<rootDir>/projects/a",
          "<rootDir>/projects/b"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need Docker here?  Would your development cycle be simpler if you used `node` directly on the host instead, so you didn't have to work around Docker's filesystem isolation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you stated that your use case is for development purposes - I recommend to restructure your approach a little.

### 1. Dockerfile

It only makes sense to run `npm install` in the Dockerfile if you will be using this image for shipping the complete code with modules. Since you're using it for development - it's useless here. Also - since you will be mounting the entire local folder into the container - remove the `ADD` and `COPY` commands.

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 4200
```

### 2. docker-compose

You should remove the `/app/node_modules` volume and change the command the container will use:

```
services:
  angular-frontend:
    image: angular_frontend
    command: "bash -c 'npm install && npm run start-docker-dev'"
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    hostname: frontend-localhost.domain.com
```

this way - your entire project folder is mapped to the `/app` folder as a volume. The `npm install` command will run when the container starts.

Comment: That doesn't work. By doing that I get this error when I run the container. `sh: 1: ng: not found`

Comment: Maybe you need to run `npm install` first?

Comment: What about the `npm install` that is already in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell exactly as you haven't provided the `package.json`, so it's impossible to fully reproduce. However - you probably have the `node_modules` in your image, but since you're mounting the entire `/app` folder - `node_modules` from the image are not available anymore.

Comment: I added the package.json to the question.

Comment: I amended the response to fully reflect your use case.

Comment: Will that avoid having a new volume each time I run the container? Also, does this means I need to have a local/host npm install to avoid having errors in VisualStudio code about missing modules?

Comment: Yes, it will avoid extra volumes. No, you don't need to have npm locally. The npm install will run in the container, every time it is started.